# How to remove the lock lever on a 2020 Suntour NEX suspension fork?

Tags: maintenance, fork, suspension

The locking on that fork is no longer working in that in locked position, the fork is as unstiff as when not.

[image: Lock lever on Suntour X1]

On other models, I've been able to remove that blue lever and  tighten things underneath to make sure the fork is locked when the lever is in locked position.

However, on this one, I've not been able to remove the lock lever. I've slightly cracked the plastic in a few places trying to pop it off with a flat screwdriver.

What's the trick?

Or is the  lever not meant to be removed on that fork?

There's not much in terms of part number written on the fork, but according to the bike description that would be:

> SR Suntour NEX HLO 63mm Travel, Alloy Steerer, Hydro Lockout

Bike is a 2021 model, so it could be [this one](https://www.srsuntour.com/fileadmin/user_upload/Downloads/Consumer/Bike/Exploded%20views/2020/Suspension%20Fork/SF20-NEX/SF20-NEX-DS-HLO-700C-50_63.PDF) with part number for that lever being FKG426. A duckduckgo search on that only turns up that exploded view.

---

## Update

OK, based on comments, I've tried to give it a good go using screw driver and a few guitar picks. All I've managed to achieve is internal tearing:

[image: Torn lever]

I can't find a picture for the FKG426 other than the very low resolution drawing from the exploded view above, but FEG426 I could and looks similar:

[image]

As you can see the inner tube-like part, now partly torn from the cap on mine is meant to hook into something and is nothing compared to the ones in youtube videos that are easy to pop off (too easy sometimes, I've had one just coming off by itself during transport on a car bike rack).

I think I've established that one cannot be taken off by brute force only, but am happy to be proven otherwise.

Over the week end, I'll try and see if I can take the whole FKE028-18 off ([image: FKE028-18]thanks @Renaud in comments), so see if that lever can be removed from underneath. In any case, it looks like I need a new one.

Though by the look of https://www.srsuntour.us/products/speed-lockout-lever-1, that's attached with a hollow screw whose head I would need to access from underneath the lever.

Strangely enough at that page, we see comments about levers coming off by themselves and others like me breaking it when trying to remove it. Possibly because there have been several iterations of that components or because the replacement you buy there is designed differently so people can undo it more easily than the original.

---

## Second update

Well, as anticipated, while I could unscrew the FKE028-18 from the fork body, I was not able to detach the FKE028-18 from the damper body underneath, but after a few attempts, I was able to screw it back on in a way that allows the lever to lock properly.

So for now I no longer need to take it off other than to replace it as it's quite a bit damaged so may allow some water in.

Comment: The grooves really seem to indicate that the cap can be popped off using a small flat screwdriver. It may be stuck. When trying to pry, could you create a bit of space underneath the blue cap? If so, maybe try squeezing plastic opening picks (like a guitar pick) or thin plastic cards (like a credit card) at a few places to create an even pressure upwards all around the cap.

Comment: It should just pop out: https://youtu.be/BUgt96qfV68?t=116 (the video is not for a NEX, but a MTB equivalent, no reason that the design is fundamentally different though)

Comment: @Renaud,yes that video shows a lever identical to the model I could pop out easily. This one won't budge. I tried olliebulle's guitar pick suggestion to no avail.

Comment: @olliebulle, the grooves/crenellations are more something to hold to unscrew the whole assembly. I could unscrew it and verify that way that the locking function appears to still work but did not manage to screw it back in a way that allows  the lever to lock properly.

Comment: @sch and with pliers instead of a screwdriver? I imagine that the tolerances should be quite tight, to avoid that it pops out when riding. With pliers, you could at least pull in the correct orientation. (note that the lever is part of "FKE028-18", that seems easier to order)

Comment: @sch to remove the FKE028-18, you need a fork wrench (reference: FAA 186, at least on the older versions of the NEX - I see they have a MTB version and a trekking version, so should still be the same). It will work even if the cap/lever is broken.

Comment: @Renaud, the FKE028-18 I can easily take off the fork body by unscrewing with multigrip pliers. What I'm not sure about is how to unscrew it from the locking device underneath given it's attached via that hollow screw whose head is under the cap. I'll try that later. Then, my plan would be to push the cap from underneath with the wheel headed Allen key thing that it should be sitting on and goes through that hollow screw.

Comment: @sch Back it out a litte, then add grease to the thread to help minimise water ingress.  Then retighten and wipe off any squeeze-out.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the problems you're experiencing, Suntour forks require the lockout lever to be pried off with a small standard (or slot) screwdriver. One wedges the tip of the screw driver under the lever body anywhere within the round aspect of the lever. Then just gently pry   the lever up and off. You may try a couple different points and "wiggle" the end of the screwdriver by back and forth rotating of the handle (motion is like you are turning a screw in, then out, but there's no full rotation...just a wiggle back and forth.

Here's a link to the Suntour video, ["How to Solve Lockout Issues,"](https://www.srsuntour.com/fileadmin/user_upload/Downloads/Consumer/Bike/Service%20videos/How_to_solve_lock-out_issues.mov) which begins with lever removal via a screwdriver.

Comment: Thanks, but see update in edit of my question.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem, the lock out lever does not "pop off" as everyone tries to tell you. This lock lever is attached to the gas strut inside the fork leg, no matter what you try the lever is stuck. When you do eventually break the dam thing the internal cog doesn't just "lift out" with the aid of a magnet either, that's another struggle completely